# I need help getting my content div container to wrap around two inside divs!

Tags: css, html

I am learning how to use divs for a layout I made and I may have the wrong approach, but what I've tried so far hasn't been working. So I have spent the last 2 hours googling and testing out various codes, but I cannot seem to get it right.

Here is my css:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
margin: 0;
}
html{
height: 100%;
}
body {
background-color: #FFF;
background-image: url(images/bckgndPattern.gif);
background-repeat: repeat;
height:100%;
}
h2 {
color:#cccccc;
letter-spacing:4px;
}
#container_shadow {
background-image: url(images/containerShadow.png);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
height: 100%;
width: 920px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
#container {
height: 100%;
width: 900px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background-color: #FFF;
}
#navbar_shadow_top {
background-color: #FFF;
height: 10px;
width: 888px;
}
#navbar {
background-color: #FFF;
height: 50px;
width: 888px;
}
#navbar_shadow_bot {
background-color: #FFF;
height: 10px;
width: 888px;
}
#container_inner {
height: 100%;
width: 888px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background-color: #FFF;
border-right-width: medium;
border-left-width: medium;
border-top-style: none;
border-right-style: dashed;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-left-style: dashed;
border-top-color: #c8c8c8;
border-right-color: #c8c8c8;
border-bottom-color: #c8c8c8;
border-left-color: #c8c8c8;
}
#banner {
height: 140px;
width: 888px;
}
#content {
background-color: #FFF;
height:auto;
width: 888px;
}
#slide {
background-color: #FFF;
height: 200px;
width: 700px;
position: relative;
left: 132px;
top: 40px;
}
.main {
background-color:#FFF;
width: 590px;
min-height: 200px;
position:relative;
top: 280px;
left: 60px;
clear:both;
}
```

My problem is when I create a div with the class main. The content div does not wrap around the div.main. The slide div seems to be okay within the content div.

As of now, I am pretty sure my divs are nested in the right places.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
--------------------------------------
-                                    -
-        -----------------------     -
-        -     SLIDE           -     -
-        -                     -     -
-        -----------------------     -
-                                    -
-    -------------------             -
-    -    MAIN         -             -
-    -                 -             -
-    -------------------             -
--------------------------------------
```

Here is a link to the project: [Test](http://www.paxeehmah.com/test)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you float an element, you take it out of the document flow. As such, the parent container no longer contains the elements. Options to force the parent container to contain the floated children:

1) Give the container an overflow property:

```
#container { overflow: auto }
```

2) Float the container as well:

```
#container { float: left }
```

3) Add a 3rd child element that clears the previous two floats:

```
.clearingElement { clear: both }
```

Comment: Are you trying these out? This doesn't seem to help. Make sure your window isn't very tall, then scroll down.

Comment: Those are just general rules.

Comment: Your rules are correct, but note that on his page, there are *zero* floated elements.

Comment: it does not work as i would like it to. it gives me a scroll bar within the content div, when i would like the page as a whole to scroll down when the div.main contains a lot text.

Comment: Then ignore me. It's late. I'm not parsing code very well. ;)

Comment: Okay, I redid my code from the bottom up and tried floating the container left, like you suggested, and that seems to have fixed my problem.

Comment: A good answer to a question that is not this question. An answer that I found by asking a question that I thought was this question but it's not. +1 I guess